# ForEach Output Result in THML Paragraph Tags

Tags: windows, powershell, html

I have a powershell script, which contain one variable by named `$GetCon` I want to add for each result into html `<p>` tag.

for example, the `$GetCon` result is:

```
 Name          Value
 -----         ------ 
 chrome         12 
 Explorer       10 
 Edge           5
```

in fact, the result inside pre tag is same, but i want to change every result inside to p tag, such as:

```
<p class="result">chrome</p> 
<p class="result">Explorer</p> 
<p class="result">Edge</p> 
<p class="resultnumbers">12</p> 
<p class="resultnumbers">10</p>
<p class="resultnumbers">5</p>
```

...And so on

**My Error syntax is**:

```
> $result = " <p class='result'>$($Names)</p> <p
> class='resultnumbers'>$($Values)</p> " ConvertTo-Html | Out-File
> "c:\a.html"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would work:

- First we create an ArrayList so we can `.add()` and `.remove()` objects
- then we have to pass the HTML as a here-string `@" ... "@` otherwise it would break the `""` maybe there's a better way to tackle this but it's the only one that came to my mind.
- Then we have to `.getEnumerator()` to make it possible to iterate over the hashtable with `%`
- Inside the `%`, we add the strings to `$result`

The code:

```
$GetCon = @{
    "chrome"   = "12"
    "Explorer" = "10"
    "Edge"     = "5"
}

$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$namehtml = @"
    <p class="result">
"@
$valuehtml = @"
    <p class="resultnumbers">
"@

$GetCon.GetEnumerator() | % {
    $result.add("$namehtml$($_.Name)</p>") > $null
    $result.add("$valuehtml$($_.Value)</p>") > $null
}
```

Output of `$result`:

```
<p class="result">Explorer</p>
<p class="resultnumbers">10</p>
<p class="result">Edge</p>
<p class="resultnumbers">5</p>
<p class="result">chrome</p>
<p class="resultnumbers">12</p>
```

**EDIT:**

if it doesn't matter if the html has `''` instead of `""`, you can just write it like this and delete the here-strings

```
$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$GetCon.GetEnumerator() | % {
    $result.add("<p class='result'>$($_.Name)</p>") > $null
    $result.add("<p class='resultnumbers'>$($_.Value)</p>") > $null
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SimonS for your answer, please answer this again to me:
If remove all <p> and insert result to the Table, how can i do it?
for example:
<tr>
<td>chrome</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr> 
with <th> which title?

Comment: @SchoolforDesign mmmhh.. i don't get that question i'm sorry.